# How do I remove "Book1.xlsx is protected" when opening a file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a file for which I get asked for a password when I try to open it. I know this password:

[image]

I want to remove the protection from the workbook, and assumed I could do this by going to File > Info > Protect Workbook, but when I do this the option for password protecting the file is greyed out, and there is no option for removing the password protection.

[image]

So can someone please tell me how I remove the password protection from the workbook?

Comment: In the Review tab, group Protect, do you have any "Unprotect" button? If you do, press it, enter password, and OK.

Comment: @harrymc I'm afraid not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to file -> Save As

Select Tools -> General Options

(See image)

[image]

Clear out the Password to open.

[image]

Hit OK, then Save the spreadsheet.

You can also follow these instruction to put the password back in place.